# Adding y-values of a function after finding them in python

Tags: python, function

I have a function `-125.22*x**2 + 3213.43*x + 2010.8` and I want to find all the values of y for x=0 until x=25, and then add all the y-values together. I tried this code but it only showed me the y-values:

```py
def f(x):
    return -125.22*x**2+3213.43*x+2010.8

for x in range(1,26):
    print(f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temporary variable for the sum :

```py
def f(x):
    return -125.22*x**2+3213.43*x+2010.8

sumy = 0
for x in range(1,26):
    print("x :", x, " - y :", f(x))
    sumy += f(x)

print("sum (y) :", sumy)
```